# How to connect two HTML elements avoiding other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've this HTML/CSS structure: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Pestov/pen/BLpgm)

I need to connect two HTML elements with a line when I choose them (clicked on first element and then second element).

I've already tried to draw straight line between them and it's successful. But the problem is, this line should avoid other HTML elements.

I'm choosing two elements like this:

```js
let selected;
let count = 0;

$('a').on('click', function(){
    selected = $('.selected');
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected') && count !== 2){
        count++;
        $(this).addClass('selected count' + count);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass();
        count--;
    }

    if (count === 2) {
        // Here I'll draw line
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a working code with your connecting line?

Comment: I will suggest you to draw all line connecting each other at beginning and hide it , when user clicks you just need to unhide those paths

Comment: No, thats why he is asking I think

Comment: That's not dynamic. What if I'll add new elements in future. @PranoySarkar

Comment: Before adding you can re rearrange the path again, if you dont go by this way then you have to do all calculation to ovoid the divs inbetween , which will be very hard

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing would be extremely difficult to accomplish using html in the way you are. If you wanted a curving line, that avoids other elements, you'd most likely have to use an SVG path and some sort of pathfinding algorithm to calculate where it should go. Instead, I would recommend you try a solution using JavaScript and HTML5 Canvas. A good starting place might be [examples](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) from D3.js. [D3](https://d3js.org/) is meant for exactly the sort of chart you're looking to create.